# How to modify a CLOB line containing a certain value by using a trigger with PLSQL?

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-trigger

I am struggling with an issue regarding a CLOB.
I would like to create a trigger (after update) which updates the column of a table which is a CLOB.
This CLOB contains lines in this form :

```
foo|132|65|12/08/2016|18395|
```

```
bar|132|54|15/08/2014|32434343|
```

I would like to modify the CLOB such that the line beginning with "foo" has the value "18395" divided by 1000. The line will look like

```
foo|132|65|12/08/2016|18.395|
```

Is there a quick way to modify my CLOB?

Thank you for your help.

EDIT : I found a way to modify the line of the CLOB what I need to do is just to modify the CLOB to replace

```
foo|132|65|12/08/2016|18395|
```

by

```
foo|132|65|12/08/2016|18.395|
```

Comment: Is the CLOB in the table the trigger is against - if so why after update; if not how are they related? How do you decide to modify the value - only if the CLOB itself has changed, or if any other column changes too, which could lead to that element being divided multiple times? How do you identify which line in the CLOB to update (i.e. why 'foo')? Is it always the 5th element of that line? (And why are you storing lines of delimited data as a string instead of a individual relational values?)

Comment: Yes the CLOB is in the the trigger is against. This CLOB comes from a response file that I can get from an SFTP connection. Before getting the response file the CLOB cell is empty and that's why I want to use an after update trigger to modify the CLOB.
"foo" is just an example, I will replace it by another string. I need to modify the value associated to this line because it is a particular case (the value I receive from the server is a multiple of the real value). I don't understand the last question.

Comment: Please edit your question to explain the whole scenario, including table structures, starting data, what the trigger action is and how you get to the end result you want. Please see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and particularly the bit about a [mcve].

Comment: Don't store delimited values. This is really a bad idea. If you **have** to store multiple values in a column (and break normalization), using JSON might be a better solution as there are many functions available to access individual elements.

Answer (score 0):

This is rather long but effective.
Firstly create a type:

```
create or replace TYPE  "array_str" AS VARRAY(10) OF VARCHAR(256);
```

Then create a function that will return a array based in a delimiter:

```
FUNCTION string_to_array (
    string_delimited   IN   VARCHAR2,
    delimiter          IN   VARCHAR2 DEFAULT ','
) RETURN array_str IS
    pls_idx        PLS_INTEGER;
    split_string   array_str := array_str();
    pls_del_len    PLS_INTEGER := length(delimiter);
BEGIN
    IF string_delimited IS NOT NULL THEN
        LOOP
    -- search for delimiter string
            pls_idx := instr(l_string_delimited, delimiter);
    -- increase the size of array
            split_string.extend;

    -- check last search of delimiter is success
            IF pls_idx = 0 THEN
                split_string(l_split_string.count) := substr(l_string_delimited, 1);
            ELSE
                split_string(l_split_string.count) := substr(l_string_delimited, 1, pls_idx - 1);
            END IF;

    -- exit from loop when last string

            EXIT WHEN nvl(l_pls_idx, 0) = 0;
            string_delimited := substr(l_string_delimited, pls_idx + pls_del_len);
        END LOOP;
    END IF;

    RETURN split_string;
END string_to_array;
```

Then create your trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER your_trigger AFTER
    UPDATE ON table_name
    FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    clob_array   array_str;
    clob_str     CLOB := '';
BEGIN
    clob_array := string_to_array(:new.new_clob, '|');
    IF ( clob_array(1) = 'foo' ) THEN
        clob_array(5) := to_number(clob_array(5) / 1000);
    END IF;

    FOR i IN 1..clob_array.count - 1 LOOP clob_str := clob_str
                                                      || to_char(clob_array(i))
                                                      || '|';
    END LOOP;

    -- do something with clob_str

END;
```

Comment: Just 1 problem with the above, but a fatal one. An AFTER trigger **cannot change values**.  If you want to change the data you must use a BEFORE trigger.

Comment: @Belayer The problem is that my CLOB is empty before the update because it comes from a response file.

Comment: You are misunderstanding what Before and After means. Both are a phase of the UPDATE statement. You can look at it this way Before executes until final values are set, you can have multiple before triggers each of which can modify the data values. After trigger(s) do not run until the data values are **fixed and can no longer be changed**.  The UPDATE statement is not complete until all triggers have completed.